# What does the C rating on a LiPo battery mean?

Tags: lipo-batteries, batteries

I see LIPO batteries specify a C rating on the label.

[image: LIPO battery C rating]

What does that stand for and how does it affect the performance of the battery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C rating is a multiplier that dictates discharge. You can figure out the maximum theoretical discharge by multiplying the C rating by the capacity. For example an 80C, 1300mAh LiPo can output 80*1.3 = 104 Amps. There is no consensus as far as I am aware as to what the letter C stands for.

It is worth noting that C rating is dubious - comparing the C rating between different manufacturers is unlikely to produce useful results as to which battery is better.

Comment: Ha beat me to it. ;) good answer

Comment: @anonymous2 Thank, you too :)

Comment: +1. I've never realized "C" in that phrase might have an actual meaning

Answer (score 3):

It's a measurement of [how fast the battery releases power](https://www.gettitanpower.com/blogs/news/short-and-long-answers-what-is-the-c-rating).

Mathematically, it's the number of times the battery can discharge in a single hour without damaging the battery / overheating.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you how fast the battery can be discharged. The max amp draw is calculated with `capacity (Ah) * C-rating`.

For example, a 1500mAh 75C battery can handle 112,5A max.

A higher C-rating reduces the risk for voltage sag, and a battery with too low C-rating can be damaged if you try to draw too much current.

Answer (score 1):

[What is a C-Rating on a LiPo Battery?](https://oscarliang.com/lipo-battery-c-rating/)

> C-Rating is an indicator of the continuous discharge rate of a LiPo. It allows users to easily calculate the maximum constant current you can draw from the LiPo pack safely without harming the battery.
>
> For example, if you have a 3S 1000mAh 20C LiPo pack, your safe max current draw would be 1000mAh x 20C = 20A.